# Translation of English sentence

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

What is the meaning of this sentence,

> "Not all sentence-equivalence questions are so vocabulary dependent but you can expect quite a few to require knowledge of very advanced words."

I could guess the meaning of the sentence, but I have no idea why the writer uses “but” while the former sentence is not in contrast to the latter, and “a few to require” is used.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

> "**Not all** men wear trousers, **but** you can expect quite a few to do so."

Or

> "**Not all** computer science graduates can code effectively, **but** you can expect quite a few to be able to do so."

This is the same contrast. "Not all X are/do Y, but quite a few are/do." It means that it is **not essential** for *things* of class X to fulfil criterion Y, **but** it is expected that **a good proportion** will fulfil it anyway.